# McKay correspondence for Irreps of $G \subset SU(2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials, quiver

We follow Alexander Kirilov's book ["Quiver Representations and Quiver Varieties"](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-174), Section 8.3: McKay correspondence: Let $G$ be a nontrivial finite subgroup in $SU(2)$. Let $Q(G)$
be the finite graph with set of vertices $V := \operatorname{Irr}(G)$("isom classes of complex irreducible reps of $G$") and with the number of
edges connecting vertices $i, j$ associated to irreps $\rho_i, \rho_j $ given by

$$ A_{ij}:= \dim \operatorname{Hom}_G(\rho_i, \rho_j \otimes \rho)  $$

where $\rho$ the $2$-dimensional representation given by the inclusion $G \subset SU(2)$. Note that $\rho \cong \rho^*$ and that moreover that $\dim \operatorname{Hom}_G(\rho_i, \rho_j ) = \delta_{ij}$ by Maschke's Theorem.

On page 143 we are going to prove that $Q(R)$ is a *connected graph*. This is done in two essential steps I not fully understand.
Two Problems arise:

first, the autor states witout proof that the number of
paths of length $n$ in $Q$ connecting $i$ with $j$ is equal to multiplicity of $\rho_i$ in $\rho_j \otimes \rho^{\otimes n}$. Why is this the case and how to see it? Say consider only the case $n=2$; ie number of paths of length $n=2$ in $Q$.

The claim is that it equals $\dim \operatorname{Hom}_G(\rho_i, \rho_j \otimes \rho^{\otimes 2})$ since this gives exactly the number of multiplicities $\rho_i$ occuring as direct factor in $\rho_j \otimes \rho^{\otimes 2}$.

Naive count of edges tells that the number of paths of length $2$ in $Q$ connecting $i$ with $j$ is $\sum_k A_{ik} \cdot A_{kj}$. Question is why it this the same as  $\dim \operatorname{Hom}_G(\rho_i, \rho_j \otimes \rho^{\otimes 2})$?

The second step is the *Lemma 8.14* & it's proof:

**Lemma 8.14**. Every irreducible representation of $G$ is a subrepresentation
of $\rho^{\otimes n}$ for large enough $n$.

> The proof argues as follows: consider the space $S^n \rho := \operatorname{Sym}^n(\mathbb{C}^2)$ of polynomials of degree $n$. Let $v \in \mathbb{C}^2$
> be such that its stabilizer in $G$ is trivial; then the orbit $Gv$ is isomorphic to
> $G$, and the space $\mathbb{C}[Gv]$ of all functions on $Gv$ is the regular representation
> of $G$. On the other hand, since polynomials separate points, for large enough
> n the restriction map $S^n \rho \to \mathbb{C}[Gv]$ is surjective; thus, for such $n$, the space
> $S^n \rho$ (and hence the space $\rho^{\otimes n}$) contains every irreducible representation
> with nonzero multiplicity.

*Problem 2*: The last conclusion I not understand: Why the surectivity of  $S^n \rho \to \mathbb{C}[Gv]$ implies that
$S^n \rho$ contains every irrep as a direct factor? Is that the case for the regular representation $\mathbb{C}[G] \cong \mathbb{C}[Gv]$?

Comment: For problem 1, have you considered the same statement in terms of adjacency matrices of graphs? The statement is that for an adjacency matrix $A$ of an undirected graph, the number of walks from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ using $n$ edges is $(A^n)_{i, j}$. For problem 2, the regular representation $\mathbb{C}[G]$ of a finite group contains every irrep.

Comment: @Joppy: For problem 2: Yes, thank you I see the idea now. Since the proof shows that 
$S^n \rho \to \mathbb{C}[G]$ is surjective, then for any irrep $\rho_i$ 
the map $ \mathbb{C}[G] \to \rho_i$ is nonzero iff the composition with 
$S^n \rho \to \mathbb{C}[G]$ is nonzero. But nonzero means that it 
contains $\rho_i$ as direct summand, and as you said $\mathbb{C}[G]$ has this 
property, that's the strategy in the proof, right?

Comment: On your hint for problem 1: here I'm not sure if I really got it. By constuction
as you said the number of walks from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ using $n$ edges is
$(A^n)_{i, j}$; indeed for $n=2$ that's exactly $\sum_k A_{ik} \cdot A_{kj}$. 
But my question was why this coincides with 
$\dim \operatorname{Hom}_G(\rho_i, \rho_j \otimes \rho^{\otimes 2})$?
(in order to keep it simple let's focus only on $n=2$)

Comment: Thinking naively surely we have of course always 
$\dim \operatorname{Hom}_G(\rho_i, \rho_j \otimes \rho^{\otimes 2}) 
\le \sum_k A_{ik} \cdot A_{kj}$ using similar way of reasoning as for problem 2. 
But why is this an equality? 
Couldn't it happen that some different $2$-paths from $i-k-j$ and $i-k'-j$ through certain $k$ and $k'$ 
which are by definition of $A_{ij}$ represented by pairs 
$(a_{ik}, a_{kj})$ and $(a_{ik'}, a_{k'j})$ where 
$a_{mn} \in \operatorname{Hom}_G(\rho_m, \rho_n \otimes \rho)$ become identical
if we

Comment: compose them as $a_{kj} \circ a_{ik}$ and $a_{k'j} \circ a_{ik'}$. (to be more precise in order to make these compositions welldefined 
we should identify 
$\operatorname{Hom}_G(\rho_k, \rho_j \otimes \rho) \subset 
\operatorname{Hom}_G(\rho_k \otimes \rho, \rho_j \otimes \rho^{\otimes 2})$) Having 
done this it could still happen that
$a_{kj} \circ a_{ik}=a_{k'j} \circ a_{ik'}$ for different paths $i-k-j$ and $i-k'-j$. 
Or is there any reason why any  'weird' behavior like this cannot occure here?